# Sleep Debt Calculator, Why isn't this function working?

Tags: javascript, function

```
const getSleepHours = (day) => {
    switch (day) {
        case "monday":
            return 6;
            break;
        case "tuesday":
            return 7;
            break;
        case "wednesday":
            return 9;
            break;
        case "thursday":
            return 8;
            break;
        case "friday":
            return 9;
            break;
        case "saturday":
            return 10;
            break;
        case "sunday":
            return 8;
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Error");
    }
};

console.log(getSleepHours("sunday")); // should print the # hours assigned to tuesday

const getActualSleepHours = () => {
    const totalHours =
        getSleepHours("monday") +
        getSleepHours("tuesday") +
        getSleepHours("wednesday") +
        getSleepHours("thursday") +
        getSleepHours("friday") +
        getSleepHours("saturday") +
        getSleepHours("sunday");
    return totalHours;
};

const getIdealSleepHours = (idealHours) => idealHours * 7;

//console.log(getActualSleepHours());
//console.log(getIdealSleepHours());

const calculateSleepDebt = () => {
    const actualSleepHours = getActualSleepHours();
    const idealSleepHours = getIdealSleepHours(8);


    const SleepDebt = idealSleepHours - actualSleepHours;
    console.log(SleepDebt);
    let time = '';
    const SleepHourFunction = () => {
        if (SleepDebt > 1) {
            return time = ("hours");
        } else if (SleepDebt < 1) {
            return time = ("hours");
        } else if (SleepDebt == 1) {
            return time = ("hour");
        } else {
            return 'error';
        }
    }
    SleepHourFunction();

    if (actualSleepHours == idealSleepHours) {
        console.log("You got the perfect amount of sleep. Keep it up!");
    } else if (actualSleepHours > idealSleepHours) {
        console.log(
            "You got more sleep than neccessary. You are over by " + -SleepDebt + " " + time + "."
        );
    } else if (actualSleepHours < idealSleepHours) {
        console.log(
            "You need more sleep, get some rest. You are under by " + SleepDebt + " " + time + "."
        );
    } else {
        console.log("Error");
    }
};

calculateSleepDebt();
```

Here is the whole code.

```
const SleepDebt = idealSleepHours - actualSleepHours;
console.log(SleepDebt);
let time = '';
const SleepHourFunction = () => {
    if (SleepDebt > 1) {
        return time = ("hours");
    } else if (SleepDebt < 1) {
        return time = ("hours");
    } else if (SleepDebt == 1) {
        return time = ("hour");
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}

SleepHourFunction();
```

This is what I tried. I am doing one of the Codecademy projects rn, almost finished, but I want to create a function where if the sleep debt hours is = 1, then it returns the singular term 'hour', and if it's multiple then returns the plural term 'hours'. It just keeps repeating hours regardless, I don't see why the function isn't executing how I want it. Does anybody have a clue? I am new to coding, so if this is a really simple problem, please be patient with me. Cheers.

.......................................

!UPDATE. played around with it and took in the feedback I figured it out
this is how I fixed it

```
if (SleepDebt > 1) {
    return time = ("hours");
} else if (SleepDebt === 1 || SleepDebt === -1) {
    return time = ("hour");
} else if (SleepDebt < 1) {
    return time = ("hours");
} else {
    return 'error';
}

SleepHourFunction();
```

Thanks so much for your answers guys it helped! :)

Comment: Where and how are you running this JS? Do you know how to use your debugger?

Comment: `else if(SleepDebt == 1) { return time = ("hour"); }` however, `SleepDebt = -1`. And `-1 !== 1`

Comment: The functon should take the number as a parameter, not use a global variable.

Comment: @Dai theres like a console part of the codecadmey lessons. Idk what a debugger is, i did do some lessons, and i understand that error messages send back what line the error is and what the error may be.

Comment: yes @VLAZ. but if i change code, which when I do to make it 1, it still does not give me the singular word hour, it still gives me 'hours'